# D3 scrolling xAxis with time

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Here is the chart in realtime. https://codepen.io/FaridNaderi/pen/weERBj I have a scrolling line chart that is being updated in realtime as data comes in.

This is how I currently initialize the xAxis

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
.domain([0, n - 1])
.range([0, width]);
```

and I have a tick function at the bottom of the js code that initializes the scrolling of the data.

What I would like to do is replace the static xAxis with one that scrolls and shows the current time, similar to the scrolling xAxis at the bottom of this page. http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/1apL7jwf/1/

I want to implement the xAxis similar to how I have the scrolling graph, where it generates the values off screen and then transitions them on screen at a set interval.

I have tried adding code to update the xAxis but have had no success so far.

```
now = new Date();
x.domain([now - (n-2) * duration, now - duration]);
d3.select(".xaxis").transition().call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```